# Model-view-controller pattern for javascript game (Three.js). Good idea?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, three.js, game-engine

I'm developing a 3D game in three.js that runs completely on frontend (currently). Is it a good idea that I completely separate model (state) and view?

For example I now directly manipulate (translate, rotate) my moving objects when needed, but instead I'm thinking of holding and manipulating a vector of their position in a model (state of game), and then set the position of the object at that vector each frame. The same I must somehow store the rotation of the object, and set it each frame in the view.

Concrete example:
When left arrow key is pressed I just translate the player object to the left. I would instead, for each frame, set player object to the current vector in the model, and on left arrow translate the vector in the model.

Model-view pattern seems like a good architectural idea, but I'm afraid it will hit performance?

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the Controller in the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern. The controller decides how the view should be updated when the model changes.

In the first part of your concrete example the view code monitors the left arrow key stroke. This is a bad idea because every frame is slowed down by you checking to see if a left arrow was pressed.

In the second part of your concrete example the controller monitors the left arrow key stroke and updates the model accordingly. This is good because the controller only runs the code for a left arrow once when it happens. It also means the controller can decide how to deal with things like multiple key presses or a key held down.

The view code runs in the frame update (fast = 60 frames per second) WebGL part of the browser. The left arrow key code runs in the (slow) event queue part of the browser. Performance wise you should optimise the code that runs in the frame update.